# How to count unique values in column A, based on multiple other colums

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help with an attendance database. I am trying to count how many different unique Student IDs are in column A if column B = "English Corner" and Column C=" September" and Column D = "2019".

For instance we have the following table:

```
Column A    //    Column B       //  Column C   // Column D //
Student ID  //     Event type    //  Month      //   Year   //
12345       //   English Corner  //   September //  2019    //
14432       //   Coffee Chat     //   August    //  2018    //
12345       //   English Corner  //   September //  2019    //
14432       //   Coffee Chat     //   August    //  2018    //
12345       //   English Corner  //   September //  2019    //
14432       //   Coffee Chat     //   August    //  2018    //
```

In this case I need a formula to count if column B = English Corner and Column C = September and column D = 2019 then how many unique student IDs are there in Column A?

Comment: You can use the `Advanced Filter`.  Check `unique records only` and use the `SUBTOTAL` function to get the Count of the visible rows.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. Create a Pivot table from your data range
2. Use *Student ID* as rows, *Event type* as values, and *Year*, *Month* and *Event type* as Filters
3. Set *Year* = "2019", *Month* = "September", *Event type* = "English Corner"
4. Create a new Name with Name = PTRows and formula `=OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$4,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$B:$B))` - the data range of the Pivot table starts on the 4th row ($B$4) and the name of Sheet with the Pivot table is Sheet2
5. Put a formula `=ROWS(PTRows)-2` into any cell out of the Pivot table.
6. You should see this: [image: Example]

Best regards, Lukas